# How to solve a malformed response using Transaction Object on Google DialogFlow?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I don't understand why following Transaction Decision Object throws an malformed response.

Whenever I want to jump from one intent to the intent where this object is passed, I got this error.

MalformedResponse
Failed to parse Dialogflow response into AppResponse because of invalid platform response: Tried to parse data from system intent but failed

```
{ 
   "@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.actions.v2.TransactionDecisionValueSpec",
   "orderOptions":{ 
      "requestDeliveryAddress":false,
      "customerInfoOptions":{ 
         "customerInfoProperties":[ 
            "EMAIL"
         ]
      }
   },
   "paymentOptions":{ 
      "actionProvidedOptions":{ 
         "displayName":"Bezahlung im Markt",
         "paymentType":"ON_FULFILLMENT"
      }
   },
   "proposedOrder":{ 
      "id":"Max-Mustermann 2-417-2019-09-20T12:16:45.667Z",
      "cart":{ 
         "merchant":{ 
            "name":"MediaMarkt Passau"
         },
         "lineItems":[ 
            { 
               "name":"SONY PlayStation 4™ 500GB Black",
               "id":"SONY PlayStation 4™ 500GB Black",
               "quantity":1.0,
               "type":"REGULAR",
               "price":{ 
                  "amount":{ 
                     "currencyCode":"EUR",
                     "nanos":9.0E7,
                     "units":"252"
                  },
                  "type":"ACTUAL"
               },
               "image":{ 
                  "url":"https://pics.redblue.de/artikelid/DE/2490314/CHECK",
                  "accessibilityText":"Image logo"
               },
               "description":""
            }
         ],
         "notes":"Abholbereit in wenigen Werktagen"
      },
      "otherItems":[ 
         { 
            "name":[ 
               "Preis ohne MwSt."
            ],
            "id":"subtotal",
            "price":{ 
               "amount":{ 
                  "currencyCode":"EUR",
                  "nanos":9.0E7,
                  "units":"252"
               },
               "type":"ACTUAL"
            },
            "type":"SUBTOTAL"
         },
         { 
            "name":[ 
               "MwSt. 19%"
            ],
            "id":"tax",
            "price":{ 
               "amount":{ 
                  "currencyCode":"EUR",
                  "nanos":9.0E8,
                  "units":"47"
               },
               "type":"ACTUAL"
            },
            "type":"TAX"
         },
         { 
            "name":[ 
               "Versandkosten"
            ],
            "id":"delivery",
            "price":{ 
               "amount":{ 
                  "currencyCode":"EUR",
                  "nanos":0.0,
                  "units":"0"
               },
               "type":"ACTUAL"
            },
            "type":"DELIVERY"
         }
      ],
      "totalPrice":{ 
         "amount":{ 
            "currencyCode":"EUR",
            "nanos":0.0,
            "units":"299.99"
         },
         "type":"ACTUAL"
      },
      "extension":{ 
         "@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.actions.v2.orders.GenericExtension",
         "locations":[ 
            { 
               "type":"PICK_UP",
               "location":{ 
                  "name":"MediaMarkt Passau",
                  "postalAddress":{ 
                     "addressLines":[ 
                        "Regensburger Str. 37"
                     ],
                     "postalCode":"94036",
                     "locality":"Passau"
                  },
                  "phoneNumber":"0851/95593-0"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "presentationOptions":{ 
      "callToAction":"BUY"
   }
}
```

Comment: Are you passing this from fulfillment?

Comment: Yes I do. All the code in backend is invoked by the fulfillment.

Comment: Yes, but what exactly is wrong on it? I compared it to one that was working. And both of the were identical. Only other names and prices for the values, but the format was the same.

Comment: I'm getting the same error, and the JSON is made by the actions-on-google Java SDK.